# How to connect mysql in dotnet 6.0 webassembly + client + server api sample project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-webassembly

I'm learning dotnet 6.0 webassembly + client + server api, i created a project (dotnet 6.0 webassembly + client + server api) and try to connect to mysql

the db only have one table

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         localhost
-- Server version:               10.4.18-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Version:             11.3.0.6295
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

-- Dumping structure for table blazorhelloworld.people
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) DEFAULT '0',
  `LastName` varchar(50) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- Dumping data for table blazorhelloworld.people: ~3 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `people` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `people` (`Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES
    (1, 'Tim', 'Corey'),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Smith'),
    (3, 'Sam', 'Storm');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `people` ENABLE KEYS */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IFNULL(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 1) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_NOTES, 1) */;
```

here is the full project

[file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TOeWQA6hvfN3doYFozEfvBWgW5RV_vjh/view?usp=share_link)

the main part of testing mysql sql connection is

```
using a1.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using a1.Shared.Models;
using DataLibrary;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace a1.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<PeopleController> _logger;

        public PeopleController(ILogger<PeopleController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        private async Task<List<PersonModel>> getAllPeople() {

            List<PersonModel> people;
            DataAccess data = new DataAccess();

            string sql = "select * from people";
            Console.WriteLine(sql);
            people = await data.LoadData<a1.Shared.Models.PersonModel, dynamic>(sql, new { }, "Server=localhost;Port=3306;database=blazorhelloworld;user id=root;password=Abcd1234");

            return people;

        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<PersonModel> Get()
        {
            List <PersonModel> people = await getAllPeople();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", people));
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm try to access https://localhost:7146/fetchpeople, but the console.write write nothing, anyone can help?

Comment: and how "fetchpeople" would translate to "PeopleController" controller ?

Comment: If you are learning how to do all this stuff, you're going to get by much faster if you actually run through tutorials and guided learning, than just trying to guess everything. There's so much here to tell you that it doesn't fit at all.

Comment: How are you testing this code? Do you debug the code?

Comment: @chetan visual studio 2022, there is a file link

Comment: People are not going thru your entire project and debug on your behalf to find the issue in the heap of code. That's why you need to provide minimal code which we can use to reproduce the problem. If you are able to debug the code you should be able to figure out if there is any error or not.

Comment: @DavidG i follow this tutorial but the project structure is different https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JxC6EUxbDo